# Using Thymeleaf templates out of the Jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring-boot application using Thymeleaf as the view engine and I want to use a folder outside the deployed Jar as the source of the Thymeleaf templates, I set the variable:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

The "/templates/" is next to the Jar with the HTML files but I get an exception that Thymeleaf cannot resolve the templates, I've tried many configurations like:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates/
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates
```

etc, not nothing works. What am I doing wrong, it is even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, looks like the way to do it is setting the value using the file url like this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./templates/
```

It Works now.

Comment: Hi,
 I ran into similar problem. Just want to know if this is the best way to solve the problem. Would using the packaging as war instead of jar be a more natural solution? I'm imagining WAR would be extracted into directories. So we don't have to do maven tricks to create two files. one jar. another /templates. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make JAR not WAR

Answer (score 0):

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

when returen view name , should be  relative path, not start with "/"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./templates/` was not working for me, but I found another way around. I added FileTemplateResolver bean to my configuration:

```
@Bean
FileTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    FileTemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("./templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}
```